# Howto see if duplicate values exist in two colums in excel and consolidate them using vba

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to transform a table which currently looks like this:

```
OI  Buy Securities for UPP          100000  0.622   0.624   62381.05
OI  Buy Securities for DIC          30000   1.57    1.575   47239.525
OI  Buy Securities for DIC          26220   1.57    1.574   41278.605
OI  Buy Securities for DIC          10000   1.57    1.574   15743.175
OI  Buy Securities for DIC          30000   1.57    1.574   47229.525
OI  Buy Securities for DIC          3780    1.57    1.574   5950.92
OI  Buy Securities for DIB          50000   3.18    3.189   159447.25
OI  Buy Securities for EMAAR    50000   5.3 5.315   265738.75
OI  Buy Securities for AIRARABIA    100000  1.22    1.223   122345.5
```

To look like this:

```
OI  Buy Securities for UPP          100000  0.622   0.624   62381.05
OI  Buy Securities for DIC          100000  1.57    1.574   157441.75
OI  Buy Securities for DIB          50000   3.18    3.189   159447.25
OI  Buy Securities for EMAAR    50000   5.3 5.315   265738.75
OI  Buy Securities for AIRARABIA    100000  1.22    1.223   122345.5
```

This table is the log of daily transactions which i have incurred. I need to consolidate trades which are of the same Security and for the Same Price into a single trade. The columns are : Security Description, Volume, Share Price, Average Price after Commission, Total Transaction Value. in that order. The total transaction value is the volume*the average price after commission. I need to create this second table besides the first one so column M onwards on the excel sheet. Everyday I get a new file from the broker which looks like this and I need to modify it to look like the second table. Can you please suggest someway I can automate this using VBA. or perhaps a macro. I cannot use a pivottable for what I do unfortunately otherwise it would have been quite simple.

Comment: Create a new worksheet, with one row for each security, and use the `SumIf` formula?

Comment: In addition, you can get the unique 'Security Description's by selecting Data > Advanced. Select the descriptions range, check "Unique Records Only" and copy to another location (Column M?). That will give you your unique records and then you can use the `SUMIF` like @DavidZemens suggested

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I tried what you mentioned DavidZemens, but the names of the securities are always changing in the first table. Secondly I need to write a VBA script to do this since It will be a function I call as part of a larger program. So Please if any help is given on that end I appreciate it.

Comment: I also want to mention that I want to create the new table on the second worksheet...fyi

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you want. Both Sheet1 and Sheet2 must exist in this example. Sheet1 must contain the starting data.

Sub ConsolidateSpecial()
   ' First Copy Sheet to a work area
   For iRow = 1 To 65535
      If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1) = "" Then Exit For
      For iColumn = 1 To 5
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, iColumn) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, iColumn)
      Next
   Next
   
   ' Now Colidate Cells
   For iRowFirstSet = 1 To 65535
      If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 1) = "" And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 2) = "" Then Exit For
      For iRowSecondSet = iRowFirstSet + 1 To 65535
         If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 1) = "" And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 2) = "" Then Exit For
         If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 1) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 1) Then
            If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 3) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 3) Then
               Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 2) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 2) + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 2)
               Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 4) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 4)
               Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 5) = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowFirstSet, 5) + Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 5)
               Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRowSecondSet, 1).Clear
            End If
         End If
      Next
   Next
   
   ' Now Delete Blank Rows
   For iRow = 1 To 65535
      If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 1) = "" And Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 2) = "" Then Exit For
      If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(iRow, 1) = "" Then
         Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows(iRow).Delete
         iRow = iRow - 1
         If iRow < 1 Then iRow = 1
      End If
   Next
   
   MsgBox "done"
End Sub